# returning specific rows from 10-20 how

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

for this query in SQL Server 2012:

```
SELECT BusniessEntityID, LastName, FirstName
FROM Peron.product
ORDER BY LastName, FirstName
```

how can I modify the query written so that it returns only 10 rows starting at row 20.

Comment: what database is this on?

Comment: I think you are trying it in `MSSQL2012`. Tagged it accordingly.

Comment: i did mention sql2012 !?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT BusniessEntityID, LastName, FirstName
FROM Peron.product
ORDER BY LastName, FirstName
LIMIT 19, 10
```

Limit from the 20th record, for ten records. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html

**Edit**:
Although this is MySQL syntax... I shouldn't be answering questions so late in the evening..,

**Edit2**:
SQL 2012 supports this behavior through offset and fetch: http://dbadiaries.com/new-t-sql-features-in-sql-server-2012-offset-and-fetch

Non-tested query:

```
SELECT BusniessEntityID, LastName, FirstName
FROM Peron.product
ORDER BY LastName, FirstName
OFFSET 19 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

It also shows paging using CTE, which can be used in older versions of MSSQL as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to achieve it in `SQL Server 2012`. Then below query can help you

```
SELECT BusniessEntityID, LastName, FirstName
FROM Peron.product
ORDER BY LastName, FirstName
OFFSET 10 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: What do you mean by `SQL2012`? Which RDBMS you are using? SQL Server,Oracle,MySQL,PostgreSql,Others ...? Clear it up first.